# Kirchhoff's Laws exercise

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

So I am solving this exercise. The problem given is to calculate the Voltage between ab. I calculate to 16V but the answer is 4V. I found out that they did not include Voltage between eb. I wonder why is that?

Edit: I applied KCL to calculate I.

The current to node *c*, I call it I*c*

> I*cd* = U*cd*/R*cd* = 6V/3ohm = 2A
>
> I*cd* = I*ac* + I*c* -> 2A = I*ac* + 3A -> I*ac* = -1A
>
> I*cd* = I*de* (as the current to node e isn't interact with the circuit based according to the picture).
>
> I*e* = U*e* / R*e* = 12V/4ohm = 3A
>
> I = I*de* - I*e* = 2A - 3A = -1A

Secondly, I use KVL to find U*ab*

> -U*ab* + U*ac* + U*cd* + U*de* - U*e*(U at the node *e*) + U*eb* = 0
>
> U*ab* = -2V+6V+12V-12V+12V
>
> U*ab* = 16V

[image: The exercise]

Comment: Without knowing the current through the 2 ohm resistor this appears to be impossible to solve. Please edit the question to show how you calculated your answer.

Comment: Please show how you obtained 16V by editing your question

Comment: @Transistor sure, I'll look back at the problem and edit it right away!

Comment: @Transistor When there is a 6V across the 3 ohm resistor, you know the current through it and therefore the current through the 2 ohm resistor as well

Comment: @muyuatan no need to assume what is connected to that node

Comment: @Huisman yes, I thought Transistor could not be mistaken :D I deleted after few seconds however.

Comment: @Transistor, the current through the 2 ohm resistor can be determined from the given information.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There is an **ideal** current source of 3 amperes, which means it will arrange the things to make 3 amperes flow through it in the direction of the arrow, no matter what happens.

We are provided that voltage across the 3 ohms resistor is 6 V, which leads a 2 amperes of current through it from *c* to *d*. So, the remaining 1 ampere must be flowing through 2 ohms resistor. Making node *c* higher in potential than node *a* by 2 V.

Here I have used Kirchoff's Current Law, which states, the current entering to any node will be equal to the current leaving that node.

- Start from node *a*, when you pass to node *c*, you are now at 2 volts higher with respect to your starting point, node *a*.
- Move towards node *d*, you are lowered by 6 volts, so you are at `2 - 6 = - 4 volts` now.
- Pass to node *e*, the current can be calculated as 2 amperes by applying KCL. You again went to a lower potential by 12 Volts(6 ohms * 2 amperes). You are now at `2 - 6 - 12 = -16 Volts`.
- Finally, pass to node *b*, you have gained 12 Volts, which -at the end- sums up to `2 - 6 - 12 + 12 = - 4 volts`.

So the change in the voltage while going from node *a* to node *b* is -4 Volts. Which means node *a* is higher in potential than node *b* by 4 Volts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It all make sense now :D

Comment: I thought that 12V at node *e* means the voltage drop 12V there so I add it in. Silly me...